# Get a valid token with Invoke-WebRequest and use with application

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

[image: Expose API][image: API Permissions]I am using PowerShell to get a token, there are 2 ways to get the token, when I supply the following parameters:
UserName, password, ClientID, Client Secret

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TentantID/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method Post -Body @{
    grant_type = "password"
    client_id = ""
    username = ""
    password = ""
    client_secret = ""
    scope = 'openid offline_access https://xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/xxxxx/user_impersonation'
}
$token = (ConvertFrom-Json $response.Content).access_token
```

For this token I can work and make actions

When I am using this script and also get a token but I don't have permissions:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method Post -Body @{
    grant_type = "client_credentials"
    client_id = ""
    client_secret = ""
    scope = 'openid offline_access https://xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/xxxxx/.default'
}
$token = (ConvertFrom-Json $response.Content).access_token
```

I added the following permission to the right application (under API permissions)
Directory.Read.All and Group.Read.All
There are more rows with type delegated (I added the same rows to type application)

Regarding the Expose an API section, there is only one row:

```
https://xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/xxxxx/user_impersonation
```

What am I missing?
I want to work without to insert user and password !!!

Comment: Don't understand your question

Comment: Please include screenshots of your exposed API and API permissions from portal by editing your qns.

Comment: You cannot get Delegated permissions in token generated with client credentials flow. To get Application permissions in token, change scope to https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Comment: With the token I cannot even read. 
I am not sure I understand what are you suggesting

Comment: Replace with https:// graph.microsoft.com/.default ?

Comment: What are you trying to read, user info?

Comment: Now I get 
StatusCode          : Unauthorized
ReasonPhrase        : Unauthorized

Comment: When you decode the token, are you getting any permissions in roles claim?

Comment: For example to read as I can do if I get the token as a user...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256462/discussion-between-venkat-v-and-bandit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get a valid token with Invoke-WebRequest and use with application

You cannot get delegated permissions in token generated with client credentials flow. To get application permissions in token and read the user information, change scope to  graph.microsoft.com/.default

If you're using a `customized API` to read the information, username and password or authorization code flow is the only available options.

Here is the `PowerShell` code to read the user information using client credentials by using `Microsoft Graph`.

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/226cf998-ddcc-4005-acfb-9bbfa7d40283/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method Post -Body @{
    grant_type = "client_credentials"
    client_id = ""
    client_secret = ""
    scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
}
$token = (ConvertFrom-Json $response.Content).access_token

$graphApiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"

$usersResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $graphApiUrl -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $token"
}
$usersResponse.value | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "User Display Name: $($_.displayName)"
    Write-Host "User Principal Name: $($_.userPrincipalName)"
    Write-Host "----------"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Token response in JWT.ms

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Venkat V
Now I got Unauthorized. 
Can you help me to understand how to add an application to a group?
I guess the token is not part of the right group and I get a token when I supply also my username and password

Comment: Do you want to add a group to Application (Azure AD Application)?

Comment: I want to add Azure AD Application to group